# IF condition in mysql script

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am trying to write a script to patch our mysql database. Something like this I can run:

```
If IsTargetVersion(1.1) 
THEN
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
END IF;
```

The funny thing I found about MySql is: it doesn't support if condition in script. I don't want to create a store procedure, call it and drop it in my script. That looks stupid...

Does anybody have better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what exactly is **IsTargetVersion**?

Comment: a function to tell the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (pattern) solution just a workaround which will help you to use IF condition in the MySQL scripts -

```
SET @s = IF(IsTargetVersion(1.1), 'ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB', 'DO SLEEP(0)');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: Your answer is amazing!