# using IF in MySQL (not the function)

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have what feels like a simple question, but can't seem to get it right. I'm just trying to execute a regular IF ... THEN ... logic, but can't seem to get it right:

```
set @var:=2;
if @var=1 THEN select 'hello';
```

I get:

> ERROR 1064 (42000):
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'if @var=1 THEN select 'hello'' at line 1

What am I missing?

Comment: You can execute these statements only in a procedure or function.

Comment: it's almost hard to believe. do they have any justification for such a cruel and unusual requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but only inside of functions, procedures and triggers like so:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS anyname//
CREATE PROCEDURE anyname()
BEGIN
    IF @var1 = 1 THEN
        SELECT 'hello';
    END IF;
END//
SET @var1 := 1;
CALL anyname()//
```

Comment: I think all of us need more details on your goal before we can offer a qualified answer.

Comment: what details? I'm starting to think that I'm the only one that has ever used a conditional statement in a batch mode :)  If you need any additional information please ask away.

Comment: here is one example of a work around that I found. Although would like to avoid it if I could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899663/if-condition-in-mysql-script

Comment: So you are unable to put your script inside of a procedure?

Comment: not in this case. I'll just go with the wierd workarounds. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) instead.

```
SET @var:=2; 
SELECT CASE WHEN @var=1 THEN 'hello' ELSE 'no hello' END;
--prints 'no hello'

SET @var:=2; 
SELECT CASE WHEN @var:=1 THEN 'hello' ELSE 'no hello' END;
--prints 'hello'
```

I hope the idea is clear with above examples.

**Edit:** to address OP's additional concerns, You can incorporate `select`s in `case` statements, but you should enclose in brackets. For eg.

```
SET @var:=2; 
SELECT CASE WHEN @var:=1 THEN (select 'hello') ELSE (select 'no hello') END;
```

One thing to notice is that it should return back only one value (from one row and a column)

Comment: thanks, but it won't work for something even slightly more complicated such as for example:  if @var=1  select *from tableX  else  select * frm tableY

Comment: @MorDeror like what? I'm sure there is a way out

Comment: @MorDeror it works too. see my edit. If you are telling us what exactly are u trying to achieve, then we can help better

Comment: thanks @nawfal, but getting just one column back is probably not going to cover most use cases

Comment: @MorDeror Yes it wont cover most cases, but you having to get retrieve multiple columns through if else logic is a code smell. I smell a design flaw. I ask you to post the actual requirement, there will be always a better alternative

Comment: it seems to me that retrieving data from a certain table given a condition is not such a terrible design flaw. :)   As far as what I was originally after was to check if a row exists before attempting an insert.

Comment: @MorDeror it is not, and that is why you have `WHERE` and `CASE` and `IF` but they are meant for different purposes. You are kind of asking for `WHERE`'s functionality in `CASE`. If you want to conditionally insert then thats a complete different thing but which is easily do-able than these hacks. See this link for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302714/mysql-conditional-insert-with-dynamic-values/13303723#13303723 There are plenty other similar links too in SO

Comment: thanks. It solves my problem, though enforces my opinion that MySQL should not be used for any real DB work. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I do agree MySQL is not really the best out there. Its not at all feature rich compared to other Dbms-es - it misses intersect, except/minus, pivoting capability, window functions and is farther from std ANSI SQL compared to other major players, not forgetting the illogical things it lets us do with its group by. But the reason its so popular is that its plain easy, something for which I like. Not just syntactically but even by not constraining us with roadblocks.